# How can I install SQL Server Express 2008 with Advanced Services?

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2008-express

Has anyone successfully installed SQL Server Express 2008 with Advanced Services?

I've tried several times and half way through the installation I always get the error:

> The downloaded file appears to be corrupt.

I found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/ea446b54-f03a-4e08-a582-bebbef3ad181/)  on MSDN but it seems that no one there could get it to work.  They were only successful in installing the 'SQL Server 2008 Express with Tools' (default) option.

I need to have Full-text Search so I need the 'Advanced Services' option.  If anyone has successfully installed this then would be they so kind as to share the method used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience in XP Pro SP3 and how I got through it. I went to the download page and clicked on the download link to install any version which downloads a bootstrapper (SQLEXP32_x86_ENU_Bootstraper.exe) which if you select the advanced services edition fails to load the install file (SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe) . After many headaches,disk cleanup, etc. I tried the link for the specific advanced services edition. This downloads the file (SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe) itself which can then be run. I had to run it from the command prompt, but that's probably just my persinickety system. At any rate, while there are probably more problems ahead, at least this get the installer running. It comes up with the SQL Server Installation and you have to step through it manually.

BTW I tried to post this to the social.microsoft site but couldn't log in.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's the link I was looking for, for the full installer rather than the bootstrapper.  The web page really does not make it obvious that those three links are to the standalone installers.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious if you've tried re-downloading the file from Microsoft's servers?  If I remember right there was a 'blip' where some of the files posted to the servers were, in fact, corrupt.

I agree with Thomas that there are some really funny things going on with XP SP3 and SQL Server 2008 installs, particularly if you use a non-English locale.  But the log files in that case should yield problems indicating an MSXML 6 problem (due to the MSXML files becoming protected), not a corrupt download file.

If you download the file again and run it, can you post the contents of the most recent Summary*.txt file you find on your C: drive?  Just search for summary*.txt and it should be in a folder like...

```
%Program Files%\Microsoft SQL Server\Setup Bootstrap\Log\
```

...(but I forget exactly where Express puts this).  This log file may yield better errors than the handful of exceptions the GUI has been coded to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://forums.extremeoverclocking.com/t303972.html

Answer (score 0):

as of Nov 2009 the SQLEXPRADVx86ENU.exe claims to be 502M on the download page, but downloads as 356M, and does not execute. This happens on both a T1 and a DSL connection, so I'm fairly sure it's not the download failing.

I was able to install the "Runtime with Advanced Services" by using the unpleasantly painful Web Platform Installer.

Comment: I had no problems using the standalone installer (SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe), I only had difficulty locating the link to the download.  The installer that was causing me problems was the one which downloads the required binaries from the web (SQLEXP32_x86_ENU_Bootstraper.exe).